# spark-submit doesn't work with python file

Tags: apache-spark

my problem is the following, when I launch spark-submit nothing happen. I write the following command line :

```
spark-submit -v path_to_python_file
```

I know that I have to specify the masterURL and the class but if I specified them in the command line or not it is always the same... nothing. When I pass argument I succedd to print them on the stdout but all the code that refers to spark are not launch. (I'm using spark under windows)

If someone have a clue it would be great

Comment: I don't understand why do u have a `-v` argument? I normally run `spark-submit` with the path to my python file and it works.

Comment: -v is just for verbose, it just give some information related to the command spark-submit. I already saw some program wroknig as you explain (ust the path to python file) so I think my problem is a problem of configuration of my environment

Answer (score 0):

The below is the spark-submit syntax.

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    --queue thequeue \
    lib/spark-examples*.jar \
    10
```